# Make Next and Previous on single-$posttype.php use the same order as archive-$posttype.php

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, wp-query, single, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type **events** and am displaying these events using archive-events.php and single-events.php from the template hierarchy. I have a custom query in archive-events.php

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$events_query = new WP_Query( array (
  'post_type' => 'events',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => '_fulldate',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array ( array(
      'key' => '_fulldate',
      'value' => $cutoff_date,
      'type' => 'numeric',
      'compare' => '>' ) ) )
);
```

This displays the events in order of event date ( as opposed to published date ). All works fine until I put `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` into single-events.php. What happens then is that the next and previous links take me to the next and previous event by published date as opposed to by event date.

I am a bit confused about how events-single.php is meant to know which is the next event. Should I be doing some kind of query on there as well, because I'm not at the moment? It's just a standard 'single' file.

Could anybody help me out I have been up and down this and cant find out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a filter on [`get_{$adjacent}_post_join`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1146) and [`get_{$adjacent}_post_sort`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1146) to get those to work.

Apologies, but I don't have time right now to work up the actual filters and debug them, but maybe that will get you started.

Comment: Thanks. I am surprised there's not some simple solution like a function for it or something. I would have thought that it would be in common use. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction anyway, but I doubt if I'd be able to work it out from the source code; mainly because I wouldn't know where to start, and I dont get the idea ... so if you do have any more information on it in the future I'd appreciate if you posted it here when you eventually do have time. For now I think I'll leave the next and previous events out of my theme unless someone else posts here as they're not vital.

Comment: Actually played around with it for a while and though I still don't really know much about it, I have a lot better idea than I did an hour ago. I wonder if you have time to just give me a bare bones an example of how such a filter might work. I'm sure I could work out details themselves but I don't know where to put it or how to get it actually operating in any way at all .. I read this post http://wordpress.org/support/topic/modify-output-of-get_adjacent_post_sort which seems to be in the same general area but he is talking about editing core files and anyway I tried it but it gave no effect.